# Poner imagen de fondo en todas la paginas de mi proyecto

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Necesito modificar la plantilla principal de mi proyecto en ionic 3 para poder poner una imagen de fondo a todas las paginas de mi proyecto

Estoy trabjando bajo Ionic  CLI 3.19.1
gracias

Answer (score 1):

Para agregar una imagen en todas las páginas en Ionic es necesario realizar los siguientes ajustes.

Cambiar el color del **background** a transparente en el archivo `~/src/theme/variables.scss`:

```
$background-color: transparent;
```

Agregar al directorio `~/src/assets/imgs/` la imagen que se va a usar de background.

```
~/src/assets/imgs/background.jpg
```

En el archivo `~/src/app/app.scss` agregar los siguientes estilos:

```
ion-content {
  background-image: url("../assets/imgs/background.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```